# I am trying to measure the width of the object like Measure app in iOS

Tags: android, android-developer-api

I am looking the way to measure the width of the object using camera in android.

What's the exact way to do this. For example in iOS we have measure application, select the start point and end point then it will calculate the real distance in cms. I need exact same thin in Android.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.